# Using join or not? XML Python api

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

Well i need to get 2 values together from a XML,

I need the property and the titel of the property's to get property:titel;
There are multiple property's and titels, but not every product has the same amount of property's.
So i like to create it on the fly

I have tried it with a .join but kan get it like working yet.

**The code to get it from:**

```
http://api.edc.nl/b2b_feed.php?key=1c020r2rcrc694e79538cec24ctcr131&sort=xml&type=xml&lang=nl&version=2015&new=1
```

**The code i tried:**

```
    kenmerkeigenschap = x.findall('properties/prop/property')
    kenmerkvalue = x.findall('properties/prop/values/value/title')
    basisurl = "%s"
    images = ";".join(basisurl % eigenschap.text for eigenschap in kenmerkeigenschap)
    basisurl2 = "%s"
    images2 = ";".join(basisurl2 % eigenschap.text for eigenschap in kenmerkvalue)   
    print(images + images2)
```

**I the get**

```
Eindoordeel;Soort garantie;Garantie;Man/Vrouw/Unisex;Verpakking5;Good Warranty Service;Ja;Unisex;Retailverpakking (Fles)
```

**This has to be:**

```
eindoordeel:5;
Soort garantie:Good Warrenty;
Man/Vrouw/Unisex:Unisex;
```

etc.

***Thank you all guys, as always i love the great help from others!***

Ok: the answer is partially working but i now get online te last item from the output in my csv.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
import secrets
r = requests.get('http://api.edc.nl/b2b_feed.php?key=1c020r2rcrc694e79538cec24ctcr131&sort=xml&type=xml&lang=nl&version=2015&new=1')

root = ET.fromstring(r.content)

#\\\CSV AANMAKEN INCLUSIEF HEADERS///

#voorbereiding van de csv inclusief headers comma gescheiden
filename = "edc-nieuwe-producten.csv"
headers = "ID,Artikelnr,EAN,Titel,Merk,Categorie,Prijsin,Stukprijs,Belastingregel,Voorraad,Diepte,Hoogte,Breedte,Gewicht,Materiaal,Beschrijving,Samenvatting,Voorraadtekst,Uitverkochttext,Laagniveau,Mail,Images,MetaTitel,MeteDescr,KeyWords, \n"
f = open(filename, "w")
f.write(str(headers))

#Standaard een basis array
records = []
#\\\RESULTATEN IN VARIABELEN ZETTEN///

#De resultaten opvragen uit de root/resultaten
for x in root.iter('product'):
    maten = x.findall('measures/packing')
    for item in (element for element in maten if element is not None):
        maatje = item.text
        afmeting = maatje.split('x')
    doc = etree.XML(r.content)
    for prod in doc.xpath('//product'):
        for prop in (prod.xpath('.//property')):
            expr = './following-sibling::values[1]//title'
            if len(prop.xpath(expr))>0:
                kenmerken = (prop.text +":"+ prop.xpath(expr)[0].text + ";")

    id =x.find('id').text
    titel = x.find('title').text
    descr = x.find('description').text
    price = x.find('price/b2b').text
    ean = x.find('variants/variant/ean').text
    artikelnr = x.find('variants/variant/subartnr').text
    merk = x.find('brand/title').text
    cat = x.findall('categories/category/cat/title')
    prijsin = x.find('price/b2c').text
    stukprijs = x.find('price/minprice').text
    btw = x.find('price/vatnl')
    voorraad =x.find('variants/variant/stockestimate').text
    gewicht = x.find('measures/weight').text
    gewichtfloat = (float(gewicht))
    gewichtinKg = gewichtfloat * 0.001
    kenmerk =x.findall('properties/prop/property')
    kenmerktitel =x.findall('properties/prop/values/value/title')
    beschrijving =x.find('description').text
    maten = x.findall('measures/packing')
    pics = x.findall('pics/pic')
    basisurl = "https://cdn.edc-internet.nl/800/%s"
    images = ";".join(basisurl % picture.text for picture in pics)

    #\\\GEKOPPELDE FUNCTIES///
    
    #voor de samenvatting, gebruiken we random zinnen, zo blijven we uniek in google zijn ogen. Hier word gebruik gemaakt van de secrets import.
    samenvatting = ("Bestel de " + titel + " nu voordeliger in de online " + cat[1].text + " winkel.", titel + " online kopen met korting en discreet in huis.")
    samenvattingrand = secrets.choice(samenvatting)
    voorraadtext = ("Vandaag " + titel + " besteld is morgen al genieten.", titel + " nu bestellen is morgen al genieten.", "bestel je nu de " + titel + " dan leveren wij hem morgen")
    voorraadtextrand = secrets.choice(voorraadtext)
    outofstock = "Helaas niet op voorraad de levertijd is 3 tot 5 werkdagen."
    laagvoorraad = "2"
    mail = "1"
    #We zetten alle kenmerken in de juiste opsomming voor de CSV.
    functies = kenmerk[0].text + ":" + kenmerktitel[0].text

    #\\\REPLACES VAN CONTENT EN CATEGORIE///

    #Hier gaan we even wat woorden veranderen om te matchen met de woorden in de winkel.
    beschrijving2 = beschrijving.replace(",", " ").replace("\n", "").replace("?", "? ")
    belastingregel = btw.text.replace("21", "1")
    cat2 = cat[0].text.replace("Vibo's", "Vibrators")
    #Opbouw van de categorie tree
    categorie = (cat[1].text + ";" + cat2 + ";Home")

    #\\\AFHANDELING VAN DE GEGEVENS///
    #Als er een titel is dan gaan we alles in een array zetten.
    if titel:
        records.append((id,artikelnr,ean,titel,merk,categorie,prijsin,stukprijs,belastingregel,voorraad,afmeting[0],afmeting[1],afmeting[2],gewichtinKg,kenmerken,beschrijving2,samenvattingrand,voorraadtextrand,outofstock,laagvoorraad,mail,images))


    #\\\HET INVULLEN VAN DE CSV MET DE RESULTATEN///

for record in records:

    #Schrijf de resultaten naar de csv file
    f.write(str(record[0]) + ", " + str(record[1]) + ", " + str(record[2]) + ", " + str(record[3]) + ", " + str(record[4]) + ", " + str(record[5]) + ", " + str(record[6]) + ", " + str(record[7]) + ", " + str(record[8]) + ", " + str(record[9]) + ", " + str(record[10]) + ", " + str(record[11]) + ", " + str(record[12]) + ", " + str(record[13]) + ", " + str(record[14]) + ", " + str(record[15]) + ", " + str(record[16]) + ", " + str(record[17]) + ", " + str(record[18]) + ", " + str(record[19]) + ", " + str(record[20]) + ", " + str(record[21]) + "\n")

# Sluiten van de csv (Dit moet anders is deze niet te openen.)
f.close()
```

**The result in the kenmerken is now only:** Verpakking:Retailverpakking (Fles);

**the real output from the answer is:**

```
Eindoordeel:5;
Soort garantie:Good Warranty Service;
Lulhannes:Ja;
Man/Vrouw/Unisex:Unisex;
Verpakking:Retailverpakking (Fles);
```

**But i need is this wat in the CSV:**

```
Eindoordeel:5;Soort garantie:Good Warranty Service;Garantie:Ja;Man/Vrouw/Unisex:Unisex;Verpakking:Retailverpakking (Fles);
```

```
property:value:property2:value2;etc
```

The result from Jack makes it in my csv for every product in csv is the same:

```
Eindoordeel: 5;Soort garantie: Good Warranty Service;Garantie: Ja;Man/Vrouw/Unisex: Unisex;Verpakking: Retailverpakking (Fles);
Eindoordeel: 5;Soort garantie: Good Warranty Service;Garantie: Ja;Man/Vrouw/Unisex: Unisex;Verpakking: Retailverpakking (Fles);
Eindoordeel: 5;Soort garantie: Good Warranty Service;Garantie: Ja;Man/Vrouw/Unisex: Unisex;Verpakking: Retailverpakking (Fles);
```

Comment: Your xml is not well formed; can you edit the question with a valid xml?

Comment: This is a part of the xml, not the whole one! The XML as whole is valid. It has only to do with this part, to join the 2 together as i mentioned.

Comment: I understand that; but you need to post a sample of the xml that is both representative of the whole and valid. Otherwise, people won't be able to help you.

Comment: This is the whole XML

Comment: Lol just forget to save the edit, the link to the XML is now provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you the property/value pairs for each product:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

url = "http://api.edc.nl/b2b_feed.php?key=1c020r2rcrc694e79538cec24ctcr131&sort=xml&type=xml&lang=nl&version=2015&new=1"
req = requests.get(url)

doc = etree.XML(req.content)
prods  = doc.xpath('//product')
with open('my_file.csv', "w") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')        
        for prod in prods: 
            line = ''
            for prop in (prod.xpath('.//property')):
                expr = './following-sibling::values[1]//title'
                if len(prop.xpath(expr))>0:
                    line+=(prop.text+": "+prop.xpath(expr)[0].text)+","
            
            csv_file.write(line+"\n")
```

Comment: Thx this works particialy, Now when i set it op for saving in to an CSV i only get the latest from the result:

```
Eindoordeel:5;
Soort garantie:Good Warranty Service;
Garantie:Ja;
Man/Vrouw/Unisex:Unisex;
Verpakking:Retailverpakking (Fles); "Wil be saved"
```

used: kenmerken = (prop.text + ":" + prop.xpath(expr)[0].text + ";")

Comment: Better said: i need it like indeed like prop:value;prop1:value1;prop2:value2 in my example above, it gives this, but the value does not match the prop, it is not connected with both

Now it is every time another line i think. But i need it for a product import

Comment: @TimBronsgeest I'm sorry, but I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I have edit the main post with the output that i get in mij CSV and the whole code

Comment: I'm gonna try this out to get it in my script :), thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @TimBronsgeest oops, pasted the wrong thing... Try with this now.

Comment: Hi @Jack Fleeting Wel i with your solution i get indeed every value, the only thing now is, i can't get it right in my csv script. When i use it and convert it to mine, i online get the latest result from your script and it uses it same one for every product in list.

Comment: @TimBronsgeest Not sure about that part. You may be better off posting it as a separate question with the relevant details.

Comment: I will do that, but even it is not working yet, thank you for your help. Have a great holyday season! Keep Healthy.